# How to spy a Bluetooth COM transmission?

Tags: communication, bluetooth, driver

I promise, I'm not doing something mischievous :)

I have a remote device (IMU) which communicate with a PC through a Bluetooth transmission : [an ARF7044A Bluetooth Device from Adeunis on the IMU](http://fr.farnell.com/adeunis/arf7044a/module-arf32-bluetooth-data/dp/1753619?CMP=KNC-GFR-FFR-GEN-KWL)  and a `BCM2046B1 Bluetooth dongle from Bradcom` on the PC (I'm on Windows XP by the way) .

The problem is that sometimes the IMU send datas, but the PC does not "see" them, though it is possible to send datas to the IMU : I think the communication is not broken, but it is rather a low-level software problem.

The issue appear whether I'm using a hand-made communication software coded in C, but also on "professional" software like [putty](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) or [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/), indicating a driver problem ( I'm using the btwusb Broadcom driver, version 5.6.7900 ).

My question : **Is there a way to spy an open communication between the IMU and the PC to see when and why it goes wrong, like a debugging tool ?**

I know it is not a "real" electronics question, but I have figured I might have more answers here than in stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to google "bluetooth sniffer". 
Then you'll find commercial apps with bundled bluetooth dongles like [this](http://www.fte.com/products/fts4bt.aspx), free open source solutions like [this](http://static.usenix.org/event/woot07/tech/full_papers/spill/spill_html/) and some articles that discuss updating specific over-the-counter bluetooth dongles that can be flashed with special firmware like [this](http://www.evilgenius.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/diy_bt_sniffer.pdf)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have found another way, but still tank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I stumbled into [portmon](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsysinternals%2Fbb896644.aspx&ei=3H-KUISvAeqj0QWxioDACw&usg=AFQjCNHs_oM5dTwWJkx3xW02D9b0Y6dljA&sig2=PEXAXWpVidgaJa5HcHw8AQ), which has done the trick : there is nothing wrong with the Com port driver.

The issue lies in the handshake at the beginning of the communication : I have to find how my embedded bluetooth module realize that the com port is open at the other end (there must be somewhere a transmission of a flag).